# C++ template instantiation with complex type

Tags: c++, templates

I want to instantiate a function where the template argument is something similar to the following `complexType`.

```
template <class U, class type> struct complexType;
template <class type> struct complexType<double, type>
{
  typedef type T;
};
template <class type> struct complexType<int, type>
{
  typedef type T;
};
```

I got the following in a header file

```
template <typename U>
void XYZ(
  typename complexType<U, double>::T abc);
```

and the implementation in a cpp file

```
template <typename U>
void XYZ(
  typename complexType<U, double>::T abc)
{
  abc = 1.0;
}

template
void XYZ(
  complexType<double, double>::T abc);
```

Unfortunately GCC is giving me the following compiler error message

template-id `XYZ<>` for void `XYZ(complexType<double, double>::T)` does not match any template declaration

Any suggestions of how to resolve this?

Comment: You can also not use `template`. Use just `void XYZ(complexType<double, double>::T abc);`

Comment: @RSahu a much more appropriate idea to simply overload. (uptick)

Comment: It's an explicit instantiation so `template` is required there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`U` isn't deduced by its argument. You need an explicit template specification:

```
template
void XYZ<double>(
    complexType<double, double>::T abc);
```

You can also just do:

```
template void XYZ<double>(double);
```